# C2440 cannot convert from 'void (_cdecl*)(int)' to 'void(_cdecl&)(int)

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, reference, type-conversion

I am using C++ in native mode with Visual Studio 2017 and I am **trying** to compile and run the example code found at [Debugging a Parallel Application in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-parallel-application).
For the record, I program in C not C++.  I am clueless when it comes to method declarations (among many other things).  I suspect correcting the error is simple but, I simply don't know how.

In other words, I am currently RTFineM.  I simply copied and pasted the example given in the url above and ran into 2 problems.  First it complained about something being deprecated but a simple define took care of that problem.  Second it complained about not being able to convert a type into another as stated in the title.

The RunFunc class causing the problem is declared as follows:

```
 class RunFunc
 {
   Func& m_Func;
   int   m_o;

   public:

   RunFunc(Func func,int o):m_Func(func),m_o(o)
   {

   };

   void operator()()const 
   {
     m_Func(m_o);
   };
 };
```

**My question/request is:** how does the declaration of RunFunc need to be in order for the example to compile and run properly ?

Thank you, much appreciate the help.

Comment: Yay, broken example code from MSDN again. The easiest fix is to declare both `m_Func` and `func` as `Func *` and not deal with references-to-functions at all.

Comment: Please post how `Func` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this constructor

```
   RunFunc(Func func,int o):m_Func(func),m_o(o)
   {

   };
```

the prameter `Func func` is adjusted by the compiler to the type `Func *func`. On the other hand the data member `m_Func` is declared as a referenced type.

```
Func& m_Func;
```

And the error message says about incompatibility of the types.

> C2440 cannot convert from 'void (_cdecl*)(int)' to 'void(_cdecl&)(int)

Try to declare the constructor like

```
   RunFunc(Func &func,int o):m_Func(func),m_o(o)
   {

   };
```

Or declare the data member like

```
Func *m_Func;
```

without changing the constructor.

Here are two demonstrative programs

```
#include <iostream>

 typedef void Func( int );

 class RunFunc
 {
   Func& m_Func;
   int   m_o;

   public:

   RunFunc(Func &func,int o):m_Func(func),m_o(o)
   {

   };

   void operator()()const 
   {
     m_Func(m_o);
   };
 };

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>

 typedef void Func( int );

 class RunFunc
 {
   Func *m_Func;
   int   m_o;

   public:

   RunFunc(Func func,int o):m_Func(func),m_o(o)
   {

   };

   void operator()()const 
   {
     m_Func(m_o);
   };
 };

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that worked like a charm.  Now I can use the example to follow the instructions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are  tyring to bound a reference to a temporary, namely to copy of argument passed to the constructor. You can try to run the following code snippet to see the difference:

```
struct Func {
    int _i;
    void operator()(int i) { cout << i*_i << endl; }
};

class RunFunc
{
    Func& m_Func;
    int   m_o;

public:

    RunFunc(Func &func, int o) :m_Func(func), m_o(o)
//  RunFunc(Func func, int o) :m_Func(func), m_o(o)
    {
    };

    void operator()()const
    {
        m_Func(m_o);
    };
};

int main() {
    Func f{ 5 };
    RunFunc rf(f, 2);
    rf();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for help, I very much appreciate it and what you posted works too.  I gave the tick to Vlad because his answer was correct and he was first but, I appreciate the help equally.

Answer (score 1):

This is a legacy approach. You can use standard library [functor and binder instead](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/functional.htm). For example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

static void my_callback(int i) {
    std::cout<< i << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::function<void()> functor;
    functor = std::bind(my_callback, 1);
    functor();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it definitely sounds like the example code uses legacy constructs.  The first thing it did was complain about some class being deprecated.  It went downhill from there. ;-)